# How to implement Protected Route using React Route Config

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to implement Protected  Routes using React Route config .

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you can now add `render` method in config

```js
{
    {
        path: "/restricted-area",
        render: (props) => isUserLoggedIn() ? <RestrictedArea/> : <Redirect to="/login"/>
    },
    {
        path: "/login",
        component: Login
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/6217

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need this behavior, I recommend this [protected-react-routes-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protected-react-routes-generator)

it will handle all the logic for you, you only need to provide the structure.